# Use lombok @getter and @setter to simplify method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, getter-setter, lombok

This is my original class.

```
public class HierarchyTreeNode {
    private String label;
    private List<HierarchyTreeNode> children;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public List<HierarchyTreeNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void addChild(HierarchyTreeNode child) {
        if (children == null) {
            children = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        children.add(child);
    }
}
```

I wanted to use Lombok @getter and @setter here. "addChild" should be simplified as setter method and the initialization of children should be put in constructor. I have tried the following but am unable to understand how to make it work:

```
public class HierarchyTreeNode {
        @Getter
        private String label;
        private List<HierarchyTreeNode> children;

        public HierarchyTreeNode() {
          this.label = label;
          this.children = children;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public void setLabel(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public List<HierarchyTreeNode> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        @Setter
        public void addChild(HierarchyTreeNode child) {
            if (children == null) {
                children = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            children.add(child);
        }
    }
```

My controller has the following function:

```
   if (!existingNodes.containsKey(childName)) {
            // find node or create new node
            HierarchyTreeNode node = existingNodes.get(parentName);
            if (node == null) {
                // new top level node
                node = new HierarchyTreeNode();
                node.setLabel(parentName);
                root.addChild(node);
                existingNodes.put(parentName, node);
            }
            // add child
            HierarchyTreeNode child = new HierarchyTreeNode();
            child.setLabel(childName);
            node.addChild(child);
            existingNodes.put(childName, child);
        }
```

How can I use lombok to simplify addchild?

Comment: You can't.  `@Setter` belongs at the field or class level.  Doesn't make sense on a method.

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to do. Why do you have both an annotation _and_ a mutator? I would **strongly** suggest you avoid Lombok altogether until you have a better grasp of the basics. AOP really isn't simple - however much Lombok pretends it is.

Comment: How can addchild/ the entire class be simplified using lombok and how can  children be initialized in the constructor? I am new to using lombok. My question is, how can getter, setter be used in that class?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Please check out the original class. Any way Lombok methods could be used in that class?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no, Lombok cannot create add methods or perform anything beyond simple getting and setting.

Lombok annotations are class level so the proper use is as below for what I think you are trying to do. You will need to initialize the List in the constructor.

If you do want a custom setter, that's fine.  Any implementations will override the lombok created methods.

Here is a simplified version of your original class. *label* will be null and the *children* list will be empty, not null.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class HierarchyTreeNode {

    // Lombok will create a set of get/set methods for these...
    private String label;
    private List<HierarchyTreeNode> children;

    public HierarchyTreeNode() {
      this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // This isn't a setter.  You are adding hence you need to implement.
    public void addChild(HierarchyTreeNode child) {
      this.children.add(child);
    }
}
```